# Magento 1.9.2. - Validate email if already exist with ajax without custom module

Tags: magento-1.9, email, ajax, jquery, validation

Before registering I would like to validate the email field entered by the user to know if it exists in the database.

This is my code:
`<input type="text" name="emailreg" value="" id="emailPreReg" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" title="" />`

`<button class="button2" id="btm-procedi"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Proceed'); ?></span></span></button>`

I would like the email field when the user clicks on button to have a check if email already exists in the database. In this case I would like to put an error message in the display block under the email input field.

My question is: Can i do this validation with Ajax/jQuery without custom modules?

Thanks for any help

Comment: what do you want here please clarify more

Comment: I clarified my question!

Comment: i will hint you? you can get it enter email id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need some js code, and some php controller/action (because you will have to send your ajax request to these action).

I suppose that you have a template for your form. So I will begin with a form :

```
<form id="your-form-id" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('your-router/your-controller/your-action')" method="post">
<input type="text" name="emailreg" value="" id="emailPreReg" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" title="" />
<button class="button2" id="btm-procedi"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Proceed'); ?></span></span></button>
</form>
```

and some javascript in your template too :

````
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var yourForm = new VarienForm('your-form-id', true);
var yourUrlForAjax = '<?php echo $this->getUrl('your-router/your-controller/your-action-for-ajax') ?>';
//]]>
</script>```
````

For this page, you will have to add a js file (in order to listen the event "click on my button" and to send the ajax request).

In this js file, you will have something like :

```
$j('#btm-procedi').click(function(){
        if(yourForm.validator.validate()){
            $j.ajax({
                url: yourUrlForAjax,
                type: 'post',
                data:$j('#your-form-id').serialize(),
                dataType : 'json',
                success: function(json) {
                    if(json.type == 'success') {
                        // manage success : ? send the form to another action ?
                    }
                    else {
                        // manage error : add a message,etc ... 
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    });
```

Finally, you have to create an action in your controller to check if the email already exists and return a json response. Something like :

```
public function your-action-for-ajaxAction()
{
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
            $email = (isset($data['emailreg']))?$data['emailreg']:'';
            $response = array();
            // Check if email exists
            // If email do not exist :
            $response['type'] = 'success';
            // else
            $response['type'] = 'error';
$this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response));
            }
        }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi man, thanks for reply. So with yourUrlForAjax can i connect to default controller of Magento for validate email without create others custom controller? In this case which?

Comment: No, sorry. I understood `without custom modules` as `without third part module`. You will have to create a custom controller.

Comment: Ok man, thanks for this help! I tried with your solution and works! Great! ;)